# Distributed Queries and Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) not supported in memory optimized tables

Tags: distributed, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

I have the below query (as stored procedure ) which I like to fire it from an app (Written by C# ) against SQL server 2014 , also I should mention that dbo.tbl_vwPlanningSalesProc is a memory optimized table!

- by the wayI already disabled the "Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS)" in my connection string!

Problem :
When I fire the query from management studio 2014 , I can se the result that I expected to get but when I fire the exact same query from an app (written by C# and .Net 4.5.1) I get the below Error:

---

> Distributed Queries and Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) are not
>   supported with memory optimized tables.

---

the query :

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spWeeklyStockSheetGetProcurementBrand]

AS 
SELECT   
         Brand = v.Brand       
         ,RowLevel = CASE WHEN v.Brand = 'N/A' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
         ,m = max([year])
FROM dbo.tbl_vwPlanningSalesProc v
WHERE datatype = 'Procurement'
group by brand 
ORDER BY RowLevel,Brand
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Please keep posted if you you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set 'MultipleActiveResultSets=False' in yours connection string that can happens because Memory-Optimized Tables doesn't support 'CASE' feature. All unsupported constructs you can find here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246937.aspx